# Serialized in C# deserialized in C# BitConverter and Endianness guaranteed

Tags: c#

Is it safe to assume that an `int` serialized only in C# and deserialized only in C# will not suffer from architecture Endianness given that `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` is hard coded to `true`

Comment: serialized *how*? most libraries that care about serialization: define the endianness; and in a lot of the recent `Memory<byte>`/`Span<byte>` things, there are endianness-specific APIs; so: *how* are you serializing? if you are just doing a raw marshal dump of the memory: yes, endianness is a problem - you could load it on a different-endian machine (in .NET Core, etc)

Comment: As @MarcGravell said, it really depends how you serialise / deserialise.

Comment: unrelated side tip: writing good serialization code *is really hard* (although it is easy to write code that *looks* convincing and *seems* to work; not really the same thing); I strongly recommend making use of any of the many pre-rolled serialization libraries that will do everything *for you*, letting you worry about your actual problem; happy to make some recommendations...

Comment: Ok, I admit this was a badly asked question. Serialize/Deserialize are not the correct terms here. I am just writing some ints in a file. Both readers and writes are written in C# and they won't target mono. I can put a byte in the begging of the file describing that the ints are written in little endian just for the case of some future unforeseen readers. I am aware of serialization frameworks like protobuf and message pack. Anyway thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. C# can be compiled to run under dotnetcore. Here, your assumption that `IsLittleEndian` is hardcoded to `true` is incorrect. It's hardcoded to *a value* at compile-time, but this might be `true` or `false`, depending on the compilation target.

See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/BitConverter.cs#L21

```
#if BIGENDIAN
        [Intrinsic]
        public static readonly bool IsLittleEndian /* = false */;
#else
        [Intrinsic]
        public static readonly bool IsLittleEndian = true;
#endif
```

Apparently, while .NET/dotnet core doesn't, Mono can target some big-endian architectures.